# Password list from regular expression: Bash-script killed by system

Tags: regex, bash, debian

I want to create a password list from a (kind of specific) regular expression (`{a-f}{a-f}{A-Z}{0-9}{a-z}{a-z}`) on a debian server with `Intel Xeon E3-12xx v2 (Ivy Bridge` Processor and `MemFree: 402108 kB`.

crunch (from Kali Linux) did not serve this purpose as there seems to be no possibility to work on this regular expressions, so I wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch words.txt
rm words.txt
for i in {a..f}{a..f}{A..Z}{0..9}{a..z}{a..z};
do echo $i >> words.txt;
done
exit 0
```

It works fine with the first five brackets (`{a..f}{a..f}{A..Z}{0..9}{a..z}`), but the kernel kills it when I try to add the last `{a..z}`.

I do not know why. Is it because my script has to open the .txt file again and again? Or is there another capacity problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are running out of RAM, because you create huge sequence of strings in `for` loop and than you iterate over it.

Use two loops (or better six) instead of one and you will not store all the passwords at once:

```
for i in {a..f}{a..f}{A..Z}
  do for j in {0..9}{a..z}{a..z};
    do echo $i$j >> words.txt;
  done
done
```